# Load a Package inside a Vuex Action only when it is dispatched

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I wanna import a package to use it inside a Vuex Action but only when the Action is dispatched in order to save on my entry bundle size.

My attempt on the solution:

```
export const actions = {
  async createNewBin(store, bin) {
    const firebase = require('firebase/app');
    require('firebase/firestore');

    const collectionRef = firebase.firestore().collection('bins');

    try {
      const docRef = await collectionRef.add(bin);
      return docRef;
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
}
```

The `firebase/firestore` is inside my entry file and I do not want that.

Comment: Why don't you import only `firestore`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

```
export const actions = {
    async createNewBin(store, bin) {
        const { default: firebase } = await import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "firebase" */ 'firebase')

        // You may want code that checks if firebase is already initialized.
        // Unsure if initializing multiple times throws an error.
        firebase.initializeApp({
            // your init options
        });

        const collectionRef = firebase.firestore().collection('bins');

        try {
            const docRef = await collectionRef.add(bin);
            return docRef;
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can find more detail about this approach here

[How and when (not) to use webpack for lazy loading?](https://medium.com/walkme-engineering/how-and-when-not-to-use-webpack-for-lazy-loading-bef9d37c42c1)

In general word the solution maybe like Eric answer with async/await

```
const { default: firebase } = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "firebase" */ 'firebase')
```

Or like this with Promise

```
if(iWantToLoadMyModule){
    import('myModule').then( myModule =>{
        // do something with myModule.default
    });
}
```